# How to Sequence number Apa style bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

First let me thanks for all the support by this team in solving my previous problems.

I am writing my thesis and using APA style bibliography. I need to tweak it to meet one condition as given below.

- Bibliography needs to be sequentially numbered.
  Note: APA style follows all requirements of university except, it doesn't sequentially number the references.
  Below given is the code

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt]{isuthesis}
  \usepackage{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{apa}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc}
  \newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
  \usepackage[pdftex,hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,anchorcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
  \begin{document}
  We compare the protocol with known protocols of majority quorum consensus   \cite{majority}, the hierarchical quorum consensus \cite{Hierar}.
  \bibliography{mybib}
   \end{document}
  ```

  mybib.bib file is given below

  ```
  @article{Hierar,
  author = {Kumar, A.},
  booktitle = {Computers, IEEE Transactions on},
  doi = {10.1109/12.83661},
  journal = {Computers, IEEE Transactions on},
  number = {9},
  pages = {996--1004},
  posted-at = {2011-08-14 19:55:36},
  priority = {2},
  title = {{Hierarchical  quorum consensus: a new algorithm for managing replicated data}},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/12.83661},
  volume = {40},
  year = {1991}   } 
   @ARTICLE{majority,
  author = {R. H. Thomas},
  title = {A majority consensus approach to concurrency control for multiple
  copy  databases, , , ,},
  journal = {ACM Transactions on Database Systems},
  year = {June 1979},
  volume = {vol. 4},
  pages = {pp. 180-209},
  owner = {sony},
  timestamp = {2011.08.14}
  }
  ```

Please help.

Comment: From where might the document class file, `isuthesis.cls`, be obtained? (It doesn't appear to be on the CTAN.)

Comment: Should the citation callouts in the body of the text be in authoryear style (e.g., "Kumar (1991)"), numeric style (e.g., "[1]"), or in some combination of the two styles (e.g., "Kumar [1]")?

Comment: .cls file can be found here --  [github.com/srvanderplas/Dissertation/blob/master/isuthesis.cls]

Comment: citation callouts will be in authoryear style. Giving sequence numbering is just a formality based on university guideline. there is no use of it in referencing the citations.

Comment: Guys please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

With your combination of (a) document class (`isuthesis`), (b) bibliography style (`apa`), and (c) citation management pacakge (`natbib`), I'm afraid I can't figure out how to provide a complete solution to your query: Loading `natbib` with the option `numbers` and using `\citet` instead of `\cite` does provide numerical labels for the entries in the bibliography, but it also generates citation call-outs of the form "Kumar [1]" rather than "Kumar (1991)". I'm afraid I wasn't able to figure out how to show the year label in the citation callouts while showing numerical labels in the bibliography.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{isuthesis}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Hierar,
  author = {Kumar, A.},
  doi = {10.1109/12.83661},
  journal = {IEEE Transactions on Computers},
  number = {9},
  pages = {996--1004},
  posted-at = {2011-08-14 19:55:36},
  priority = {2},
  title = {Hierarchical  quorum consensus: A new algorithm   
     for managing replicated data},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/12.83661},
  volume = {40},
  year = {1991},
} 
@ARTICLE{majority,
  author = {R. H. Thomas},
  title = {A majority consensus approach to concurrency 
      control for multiple copy databases \dots},
  journal = {ACM Transactions on Database Systems},
  year = {1979},
  volume = {4},
  pages = {180-209},
  owner = {sony},
  timestamp = {2011.08.14},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue,
    bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
\begin{document}
\citet{majority}

\citet{Hierar}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

I can't help but make a few comments. The main issue, in my mind, is the following: Given that it appears that you want to use authoryear-style citation call-outs, *why* would you (or some adviser?) want to deliberately clutter up the bibliography, by providing numerical labels that serve no discernible purpose -- other than, possibly, to reveal easily how many pieces you've cited in total by looking at the final entry in the bibliography? But then, who even cares about wanting to count easily *how many* pieces were referenced?

Instead of getting too worked up over adding pointless numerical labels to the bib entries, I'd spend some time cleaning up and correcting the information actually contained in the bib file. If you compare your original input with the cleaned-up entries used in the example above, I think you'll find a few differences.